# VB.Net Window Programming database coonection open close

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a window project using VB.net. On every form of my project I opened Microsoft access database connection on form load and closed on form closing event. So I want to ask that this is good practice to open/close database connection on every form.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the followings:

1. Would the db connection be used to update or only query?
2. How many users would open the form and connect to db at the same time?

If the users are many and they update db, I think it's not a good idea to keep connected while opening the form. Usually you may query some data upon opening and then close the connection immediately, and the same for updating.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to create/open/close db connection every time you execute some query.
Notice that by create/open/close I mean instantiating new instance of `SqlConnection`.
Under the hood ADO.NET will open real, physical connection to the database server only once and re-use it every time you will open new connection by your code.

So every query should be execute with own new connection

```
Using connection As SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString)
    Using command As SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)
        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    End Using
End Using
```

If you open connection in `Form_Load` and close it in `Form_Closing` it possible that when exception thrown while form is opened your connection will remain opened.

By reducing amount of time when connection is "opened" in your code you can handle this situation by using `Using` keyword and avoid using of "ugly" `try .. catch` everywhere

And I hope you are using sql parameters (`SqlParameter`) in your queries.